# Taurus junit-xml report is not viewable

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I get this xunit report but when I open it via several browsers, it's like this. IS there any way to get a sharable report via offline mode ? Thank you.
[image]

This is my Taurus configuration and I ran in Centos 7.

```
---
execution:
- concurrency: 2
  ramp-up: 1m
  hold-for: 1m10s
  scenario: first

scenarios:
  first:
    think-time: 0.75
    requests:
    - http://blazedemo.com/
    - http://blazedemo.com/vacation.html

reporting:
- final-stats
- console
- blazemeter
- junit-xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how [JUnit XML result](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/adfz/developer-for-zos/9.1.1?topic=formats-junit-xml-format) should look like, I don't know what else do you expect to see there.

There is a link to the online report in BlazeMeter service, report retention period depends on your [BlazeMeter Pricing Plan](https://www.blazemeter.com/pricing/), for free/anonymous users it's 7 days as of now

There is a possibility to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of `kpi.jtl` file which is in your [artifacts directory](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ArtifactsDir/) however [you will need to take some extra steps](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#CSV-file-content-configuration) in order to be able to do this.